# Add and Delete First Nodes

Tags: java, linked-list

I'd like to create a method to add an element at the beginning of the list and delete the first.

Here are my `Node`class (I'm only using `int`s and I've created standard getters and setters) and my `LinkedList` class:

```
public class Node
{
    private int info = 0;
    private No next = null;

    No(int i)
    {
    this.info = i;
    }
}

public class LinkedList
{
    public Node first, last;
    public int size;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        this.first = this.last = null;
        size = 0;
    }
```

I was able to create the `addFirst` method:

```
void addFirst(int e)
{
    Node n = new No(e);

    if(isEmpty()){
        this.first = n;
        this.last = n;
    }       
    else{
        n.setNext(this.first);
        this.first = n;
    }

    size++;
}
```

The `addFirst` is working fine but I have no idea what to do with the `deleteFirst`.

I've tried something like

```
int deleteFirst()
{           
    first = this.first.getNext();
    return first.getInfoo();
    size--;
}
```

But it's not working. Any tips?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove the first Node in a Linked List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507299/how-do-you-remove-the-first-node-in-a-linked-list)

Comment: First: `size--` must happen _before_ the `return` statement, otherwise it's unreachable and probably won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

If your `deleteFirst` method should delete the first `Node` and return its value, then you should just move the `this.first` pointer to the next and then return the previous `this.first` value.

```
int deleteFirst() {           
    first = this.first.getInfoo();
    this.first = this.first.getNext();
    size--;
    return first;
}
```